# Karate: How to call a failed scenario again with after-scenario hook

Tags: karate

I have a scenario where the scenario in a feature file will get failed with gateway time out some times.(i have provided the timeout in karate-config file, but looking for other way)

When it get failed with time-out error then with the help of info.errormessage in after-scenario hook i have trying to call the failed scenario with feature file with tag name. can it be done?

and instead of hardcoding the scenario name with tag name, can we run the failed scenario with gateway alone until it get passed

As no status code is generate unable to use retry directly after crud method

Comment: you are looking for re-trying failed tests. see linked answer. it may not be simple. other than this - please assume there is no direct support for what you want